# Create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a dictionary of dictionaries similar to the following:

```py
data_dict = {
    'first_entry': {'a': 345, 'b': 8484}, 
    'second_entry': {'a': 3423, 'b': 848}
}
```

I would like to create a dataframe of all these values, as follows:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [list(data_dict[key].values()) for key in data_dict.keys()],
    columns = list(data_dict[list(data_dict.keys())[0]].keys()))
```

I'm a bit concerned about the approach taken here with respect to accessing
the keys and such.

Note - in the above the values `first_entry` and `second_entry` are not
reliable, but the values of `a` and `b` are reliable. In the actual data I
have ~500 or so nested dictionaries, (so `first_entry` ...
`five_hundredth_entry` using the above syntax).

Comment: What's wrong with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with **`orient='index'`**. We can reset the index at the end optionally.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
      a     b
0   345  8484
1  3423   848
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index(drop=True)
      a     b
0   345  8484
1  3423   848
```